# Serilog doesn't write to text file the log of console log in ASP.NET Core 6 minimal API

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

For debugging, I would like to write all what happens in the ASP.NET service. How I will install it as service, I need to write it in a text file.

But in debugging, I can see the output in console and in the text file.

First, I configure the json settings:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": { "path": "Logs/log.txt" }
      }
    ],
```

And the I use this code in the `program.cs` of the ASP.NET Core project:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", true)
        .Build();

var miFicheroTextoLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();

miFicheroTextoLogger.Information("Prueba");
```

In the console, I can see this:

```
[17:39:22 INF] Prueba
trce: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Model.Internal.ServiceRouteBuilder[2]
      Discovering gRPC methods for GestorOrdenadores.Service.Server.Grpc.GestorOrdenadoresService.
trce: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Model.Internal.ServiceRouteBuilder[1]
      Added gRPC method 'SayHello' to service 'greet.Greeter'. Method type: Unary, HTTP method: POST, route pattern: '/greet.Greeter/SayHello'.
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[1]
      Hosting starting
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://[::]:5001
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[13]
      Loaded hosting startup assembly GestorOrdenadores.Service.Server.Host.AspCore
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: D:\desarrollo\proyectos\GestorOrdenadores\GestorOrdenadores.Service.Server.Host.AspCore\bin\Debug\net6.0\
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2]
      Hosting started
```

But in my text file I only have:

```
2022-08-26 17:39:22.057 +02:00 [INF] Prueba
```

In the text file only writes what I told to write with `miFicheroTextoLogger.Information("Prueba");` but I would like to write all what ASP.NET Core tells too.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code, where you actually set up Serilog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is wrong. First, there's no reason to create *another* configuration instance. The host generated by the minimal API template already uses these configuration sources.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

As [the docs explain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#read-configuration) the default configuration reads from

- appSettings.json and appSettings.{environment}.json
- Environment variables
- The command line

Logging can be configured through the `builder.Logger` property. If you add the `Serilog.AspNetCore` package you can also use the `UseSerilog()` method through `builder.Host` :

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));
```

In this example the logger is configured using both code and settings.

You can also add request logging by adding this after `Build():

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

Putting this together :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

The [Serilog .NET 6 Minimal API example](https://github.com/datalust/dotnet6-serilog-example) projects shows how to add Serilog to a Minimal API project configure it. It also adds a fallback logger should the startup process fail

Comment: I have followed the step for Serilog .NET 6 Minimal API example, but I only can log warnings, on trace, error or fatal or another kind of logs.

Comment: Update your question and add what you actually used. Serilog works in Minimal API programs, I use it myself. Quite likely, there's a misconfigured `Level` filter